# python subprocess.popen use preexec_fn with arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have read the python document about subprocesses, but the argument `preexec_fn` for `subprocess.Popen` can only point to a function with no argument.

Now I want to call a function with two arguments just like what `preexec_fn` does, I've tried to use global variables, but it doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Comment: were you not able to do `subprocess.check_output(cmd, preexec_fn=function_name(arg1, arg2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the arguments using `functools.partial` or a `lambda`:

```
>>> import functools
>>> def need_two_arguments(a,b):
...     print a + b
... 
>>> no_arguments_needed = functools.partial(need_two_arguments, "Hello, ", "World!")
>>> no_arguments_needed()
Hello, World!
>>> no_arguments_needed = (lambda: need_two_arguments("Hello, ", "World!"))
>>> no_arguments_needed()
Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 0):

if your target function is simple enough, you may want to try anonymous functions ("lambda function"). And, you can place this lambda function as it is or, as a function object `(ex)f=lambda x,y: x+y` and, no need to use partial nor importing "functools" package. (btw, if you want to use only partial, you can also clean up as `'from functools import partial'` and directly use partial as your local function.

`<example with anonymous function>
 import subprocess
 subprocess.Popen(<cmd>, preexec_fn=(lambda x,y:x+y))`